# Git commit is incredibly slow

Tags: git, performance, commit

Lately when I use `git commit` after changing a few lines of code, it may take a few minutes to finish. I'm unsure what has changed.

When I run it with diagnostics:

```
 GIT_TRACE2_PERF=1 git commit -m "message"
```

I get a verbose output, which hangs for at least a minute on this line. After a long time it moves on to print other lines.

```
... Some more lines ...
14:17:21.697862 trace2/tr2_tgt_perf.c:213    | d1 | main                     | atexit       |     |  0.024188 |           |              | code:0
```

Any ideas what may be causing this?

Comment: It seems to know the exit code already, so are you sure this is git's fault, and not something in your shell (for example a fancy prompt function)? Try `ps aux | grep git` in another shell to see if `git` is actually still running at this point.

Comment: @Thomas Yes this is in the middle of the Git output, not at the end of it. My bad for not explaining correctly.

Comment: Is this specific to one repository or a general problem in all repositories? Does it happen on a fresh clone? Do you have commit signing enabled (gpg is always a bit slow for me on Windows)? Have you tried different shells? What version of git are you using? What version of the operating system?

Comment: Note that the perf number, and hence the last line you showed, comes out *after* the operation. The thing that is being slow is the *next* operation, whatever that is.